# How can I split horizontally across several vertically split windows in Vim?

Tags: vim, split, vimdiff

Basically, I want to go from **1)** to **2)**
I usually do this by splitting horizontally first and then vertically, but as I want this to do three-way diffs, it is much handier to start vim by running:

```
$ vimdiff file1 file2 file3
```

And then doing something to open the split window below.

```
1)
    +----+----+----+
    ¦    ¦    ¦    ¦
    ¦ f1 ¦ f2 ¦ f3 ¦
    ¦    ¦    ¦    ¦
    +----+----+----+

2)
    +----+----+----+
    ¦    ¦    ¦    ¦
    ¦ f1 ¦ f2 ¦ f3 ¦
    +----+----+----+
    ¦      f4      ¦
    +--------------+
```

Does anyone know of a way to this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use `:botright split` or `:bo sp`, it does what you want

Comment: It does, indeed. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Hasturkun what's the equivalent for a `:vert split`, where you've got `f1,f2,f3` horizontally, opposite of OP's example, and then you want a vertical split across all three screen, so that the vert split takes up 50% of the screen, rather than half of `f1` for example?

Comment: @TankorSmash: I can't verify this right now, but I found [this handy page](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/vim-splits-a-guide-to-doing-exactly-what-you-want/), and it seems to suggest you want a `:topleft vsplit`

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks! Upvoted. What's worse is that I've actually had that page bookmarked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Hasturkun's excellent answer, you may find some of the `Ctrl-W` commands quite useful:

These are `Ctrl-W` followed by (capital) `H`, `J`, `K` or `L`.  These move the current window to the extreme left, bottom, top or right respectively.  So to go from your 1 to 2, as an alternative to using `:botright`, you could do a normal `:sp` or `:vsp` and then do `Ctrl-W J` and the window will be moved to the bottom.

```
:help CTRL-W_H
:help CTRL-W_J
:help CTRL-W_K
:help CTRL-W_L
```

Comment: This is a great answer if you've already created the split and want to move it to the very bottom.